# How can I update url with hashchange within tabs by using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tabs

I would like to get my page to display the current tab in the URL, please keep in mind I'm still learning, so my coding skills are not the greatest. I would normally use PHP for this, but I've been asked to stick to Javascript/JQuery.

So far, I've managed to get my tabs to display content dynamically within a div by using a simple script.

This is my index bit:

```
<div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3">
        <div class="custom-left-tabs -text--uppercase">
          <div class="custom-left-tabs-btn hidden-lg hidden-md">
            <a href="#lefttabs" aria-expanded="false" data-toggle="collapse">Menu<i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a>
          </div>
          <ul id="lefttabs" class="list-unstyled collapse">
            <li class="sub-heading">Getting Started</li>
            <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="pages/first.html">First</a></li>
            <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="pages/second.html">Second</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="content" class="tab-content col-lg-9 -bg--white -padding--m">
      </div>
    </div>
```

This is my script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#content").load("pages/first.html");
});

$("li").find('a').click(function(){
  var page = $(this).attr('href');
  $("#content").load(page);
  return false;
});
```

Ideally I would prefer not having all content chucked into one page. I've checked many similar questions/videos, but I can't really find the missing bit.

My question is really how should I write a script that does this extra bit of displaying the current tab on the URL.

Comment: The easiest way would be using an `iframe` instead of a `div`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I would prefer sticking to the div solution which already works, I just would like to enhance it with the URL bit.

Comment: uhhh... You see, there's a way to do that: make those pages look the same but make the tabs different. The problem is, it's less dynamic, as you have to load all the page you want to see and not just a text. If you want to make the URL bar show the URL of the page, I'm sorry but that's not possible. If you want your script to change the URL it will reload the page, and you won't see the tabs or anything else. No choice, it's how it works.

Comment: I'm trying to get something similar to this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nBbkTmQHh3M&t=1s

Comment: Sorry I'm at work right now so I don't have access to youtube

Answer (score 2):

Here this thing can be done using iframe which works well,
 but as you suggested i have tried it. here is my code.
[reference](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nBbkTmQHh3M&t=1s) same as you gave before.

Now i am showing code here
use js in this manner:

```
<script src="jquery.min.1.4.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.blockUI.js"></script>
<script>
     $(function(){
         $("#tabs a").click(function(e){
              $("#tabs li").removeClass("on");
              $(this).parent("li"). addClass("on");
              var page = this.hash.substr(1);
              $("#content_wrapper").block();
              $.get(page+".html",function(html){
                   $("#content").html(html);
                   $("#content_wrapper").unblock();
              });
         });
     });
</script>
```

and html code with "`<div>`" tag.

```
<ul id="tabs">
    <li><a href="#first">TAb1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#second">TAb2</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="content_wrapper">
    <div id="content">
    </div>
</div>
```

i have also used jquery.min.js and blocjUI.js and css
css code is here

```
<style>
ul {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
li {
    float:left;
    list-style:none;
    padding:10px;
    background-color:#333;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
li a {
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-family:arial;
}
#content_wrapper {
    width:400px;
    height:300px;
    background-color: #ccc;
    margin: 0px;
    padding:6px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#content {
    font-family: arial;
}
li.on {
    background-color:#ccc;
}
li.on a {
    color:#333;
}
```

and you will get two different page in one page.

Scrren1:
[image: first.html shown]

screen2:
[image: second.html shown]

Comment: While this is pretty much the same exact solution as on the video, my final goal as described is to enhance my initial state of loading dynamically from other folders like on my script that traverses using "find" and loads the page within the #content div.  In other words my script needs enhancement with something similar to the clip.

Comment: as i believe that using ajax, i call proper value in my main page from another page or folder with a good structure. then it is best practice that you use different page with id and call it after loading your main page. here, i moved both html files to "df" folder then you can change "href" from "#first" to "#df/first" and "#second" to "#df/second". then also it works.

Comment: or you can use php "include" tag and "if" condition. then also it will work.